# javascript setInterval doesn't call every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have two functions I need it to call one function ever 30 seconds. But when using setIntreval it calls every second. how can I fix this?

```
this.seconds = 30; // part of a class called "player" it holds a value in seconds
var _seconds = this.seconds * 1000; // converts seconds to miliseconds

this.init = function() {
    ws.send('init'); // sends "init" to the server
}

ws.onopen = function() { // ws is a local variable that holds the connection.
//ws.onopen is a method of ws it is called once per page load,
//and only if the client connects successfully to the server 
    var call = this.init;
    setInterval(call, _seconds);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there no comma between `call` and `_seconds`?

Comment: You haven't posted enough code. What is `ws`?

Comment: Also, can you provide information on how you know the function is called every second?

Comment: ...and provide a fully working jsfiddle. Usually that step alone suffices to find the error all by yourself... :)

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to this, use your function name instead call_function

```
setInterval(function(){
  call_function();
}, 30000);
```

Comment: So, provided he adds the missing comma (probably a typo) and that `call` is his function, how is your solution different? That does not seem to be OPs problem. It seems we can't really debug this issue given the provided information, that's all.

Comment: @Mörre The problem could have something to do with how he is producing the `_seconds` value (he hasn't told us what `this` is here). Putting a hardcoded 30000 value in the timeout duration would be a good troubleshooting step (but not an answer).

Comment: If seconds isn't available he'd get an error, not the described behavior. And asking him if he tried a hardcoded `30000` is worth a comment, not an answer :) Oh and that is not _my_ downvote you got there, in case you were wondering. I never downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code, how are you invoking `ws.onopen`? Currently as is, when you invoke the function, I believe the `this` context is bound to `ws`. However, your `ws` object doesn't have an `init` method associated with it.

You have to be careful with the setTimeout and setInterval functions in JavaScript. For example, the setInterval function does NOT invoke your function every X seconds. What it does is that every X seconds, it will place your function in the event queue. Only when it is that particular function's turn in the queue will it get executed. I know that this isn't necessarily an answer to your question, but I believe your question is slightly flawed because you won't be able to inherently guarantee your function being invoked every 30 seconds using setInterval.

Comment: He doesn't say he gets an error, he says it's called every second. The problem is not "debuggable" using the information OP provided.

Comment: I believe @wmock is correct. As per this code, the init method would never get called. This context is bound to ws.

Comment: @Karthik Now all you have to do is explain why OP says the function is called every second, and not that he gets an error. Why don't we stick to the facts? And they are this: we cannot say anything! You are not just speculating, you are even disregarding the few facts we have for your assumption. It may be the problem - or not. Sticking to what OP actually says it isn't. Since getting an error and being called ever minute are two _vastly_ different things I see no reason to disbelieve OP at this point. I mean, that would really be something if he confuses those two...

Comment: the comma was a mistake when I wrote the code up there. As for `ws` that applies to the `WebSocket` methods `ws.onopen` is called every time the client browser connects to the Websocket server. So basically that's only called once per page load. The reason for the `this.seconds` is because its apart of a class called player

Comment: @Michael how do you know your function is being called every second? Can you verify this?